# Solve the PDE: $u_{xx} - 3u_{xt} - 4u_{tt} = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

It is asked to solve the PDE

$$u_{xx} - 3u_{xt} - 4u_{tt} = 0$$
using a factorization, that consists in

$$\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - 4 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right) \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right) u = 0$$

**My attempt:**

I called

$$\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right) = v$$ 
and solved 
$$ v_x - 4 v_t = 0$$
making the change of variables: $x' = x-4t, \; t' = -4x - t$.  This change of variables leave us with the following "ODE":
$$17 u_{x'} = 0 \Rightarrow u(x,t) = f(t') = f(-4x-t) = g(4x+t)$$
where g and f are arbitrary functions of one variable

For the second part, we have the PDE:
$$u_x+u_t = g(4x+t)$$

I made the following change of variables: $x' = x+t, t' = x-t$, and this leave us with the following "ODE":
$$2u_{x'} = g(4x+t)$$

The answer is 
$$ u(x,t) = c_1(4x+t)+c_2(x-t)$$

I understand that the last "ODE" give us the solution

$$u(x,t) = \int g(4x+t) dx' + c_2(x-t)$$
but why is the integral also a function of 4x+t? Where I commited a mistake?

Thanks in advance!

**@Edit:** Please, don't give me a solution using another technique that is not a factorization. I think my mistake, if there is one, consists on the variables that I am choosing.

Comment: You are already done as $c_1(4x+t)=\int g(4x+t)dx'=\int g(\frac52x'+\frac32t')dx'$. If $G$ is an anti-derivative of $g$, then $c_1(u)=\frac25G(u)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be helpful to view the "factorization" technique as separation of variables.
Assume $\,x = \eta+\xi ,\,$ and $\,t = \eta-4\xi  .\,$ 
Then

\begin{cases} 
x =  \eta + \xi\\ 
t = \eta-4\xi  
\end{cases}
\implies 
\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}  = 
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \xi} + 
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial \xi}  
= \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}  - 4 \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} 
\\ 
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}  = 
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \eta} + 
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial \eta}  
= \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}  + \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} 
\end{cases}

But then

\begin{multline}
\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - 4 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right) 
\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right) u 
=
\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}   \right) 
\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta} \right) u 
= u_{\xi\eta}  = 0
\end{multline}

We can write

\begin{alignat}{1}
u_{\xi\eta}  = 0 & \implies u_{\xi} & = \int u_{\xi\eta} \,d\eta = c_1\left(\xi\right), \quad
u_{\eta} = \int u_{\xi\eta} \,d\xi = c_2\left(\eta\right),&
\\
&\implies   u & = \iint u_{\xi\eta} \,d\eta \,d\xi = \int c_1\left(\xi\right) \, d\xi 
= C_1\left(\xi\right) + C_2\left(\eta\right)&
\\
&\implies u_\eta  & = \dfrac{d C_2}{d\eta}  = \int u_{\xi\eta} \,d\eta = c_2\left(\eta\right)
&\\ 
&\implies u & = C_1\left(\xi\right) +  C_2\left(\eta\right)&
\end{alignat}

In that case it is clear that

$$
u = C_1\left(\xi\right) +  C_2\left(\eta\right) = 
C_1\big(x-t \big) + C_2\big(4x+t \big) 
$$

Since $\,c_1,\,$ $\,c_2,\,$ and $\,c_3\,$ are arbitrary functions, we can rewrite the last equation as

$$
\bbox[5pt, border:2.5pt solid #FF0000]{
u =  C_1 \left(x-t \right) + C_2 \left(4x+t \right) 
}
$$

Comment: Good answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: I am really confused how you got from $u_{\eta\xi}=0\implies u=c_1\eta+c_2\xi+c_3$, whereas the correct answer should be $u(\eta,\xi)=C_1(\eta)+C_2(\xi)$.

Comment: -1. The answer is incorrect.

Comment: $c_1$ is an arbitrary function of $\xi$ and $c_2$ is an arbitrary function of $\eta$. You should get, $u=c_1(\xi)\xi+c_2(\eta)\eta+c_3$, or $u=C_1(\xi)+C_2(\eta)$, as noted above

Comment: @player100 Thank you for pointing out my mistake!

Comment: @Artem  Thank you for the hint and for diligence!